# PHP difference between int and integer

Tags: php

Is there any difference between `int` and `integer` in PHP?

Which is the newer or more recommended use?

```
$a = (int)"3 euros";
echo $a;  // $a==3

$a = (integer)"3 euros";
echo $a; // $a==3
```

Comment: int is short for integer

Comment: int is only alias for integer.

Comment: @TufanBarışYıldırım I couldn't find a source in the manual, however it appears that `int` is favorable over `integer` considering `var_dump((integer) 1);` outputs `int 1` (php 5.3.15); `(int)` is also used more often than `(integer)` in the docs. Perhaps integer is an alias for int ...just nit-picking :P

Comment: int is the primitive type and integer is the reference type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php):

> Converting to integer
>
> To explicitly convert a value to integer, use either the (int) or
>   (integer) casts. ...

Answer (score 66):

The difference arises when we use type hinting from php 7.0+

this is valid

```
function getId(): int 
{
 return $id;
}
```

this is not

```
function getId(): integer
{
 return $id;
}
```

the second one will expect you to return an object of a 'class integer', which will cause a strange sentence:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Return value of getId() must be an instance of integer, integer returned in ...
```

Comment: This is correct. The problem is that the accepted answer from 2012 is not valid anymore.

Comment: This example is excellent: we have to ban "integer" use and prefer "int"

Answer (score 11):

No.

They are the same, they both cast the value to an integer, one is just terser by four characters.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting).

Answer (score 2):

This is not quite true, there is actually a difference between int and integer.
Here a simple example:

```
//print_r('PHP version: '.phpversion().'<br />');
//PHP version: 5.5.23

$i = '1';

function testme(int $j){
  print_r ($j);
}
testme(intval($i));
```

This little portion of code will print an "E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR"
since testme function is expecting 'int' and get 'integer' instead.

Comment: Wrong example... See: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration `...using boolean as a parameter or return type will require an argument or return value that is an instanceof the class or interface boolean, rather than of type bool`. That is why Your code doesn't working. Not beacuase of int/integer. You can try `testme((int) $i)` or `testme((integer)$i)`. It is the same result: "Argument 1 passed to testme() must be an instance of integer, integer given"